# using react with redux and Getting error in redux '=' expected

Tags: reactjs, redux

hi i m using react with redux. 1 hour before its working perfectly but now getting error **TypeScript error in /Users/invest19/Desktop/super admin/super Admin guest /invest19-admin-web/node_modules/redux-thunk/es/index.d.ts(1,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005**

Please help me for resolve this issue

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this same error. Couldn't figure it out the cause, but downgrading to redux-thunk@2.3.0 solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from typescript `3.7.2` to `3.9.10` resolved this issue for me. I was then able to update to `redux-thunk@2.4.1`.